# How do I remap the OneKey Recovery button on my Lenovo Y510p laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-8, lenovo-laptop, button-remapping

I have recently bought a Lenovo Y510p laptop which comes with a button just adjacent to the power port. This button runs the "OneKey Recovery.exe" file in the directory C:\Program Files\Lenovo\OneKey App\OneKey Recovery

Is it possible to remap this button to run other apps / open folders or files?

I'm on Windows 8

Comment: A thread about that exists on lenovo forums. Scroll to the bottom, one of the posters created a tool for it, after an explanation in the thread. http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-S-series-Netbooks/How-can-the-S10-OKR-key-be-remapped/td-p/106127 - The key is apparently hardcoded to jump to a specific location. They are different models but there is a good possibility that it may work anyway.

Comment: thanks, https://github.com/vanowm/Lenovo.OKR.button.mapper this worked